# extend list for matching dictionary keys

Tags: python

I am trying to combine multiple sub `dictionaries` and into single `dictionary` based on `keys`. The dictionary `keys` are fixed(same) and `items` are `list` that I am trying to combine.

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']

cars = ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo']

d = {}
d1 = {'a': fruits, 'b': cars}
d2 = {'a': cars, 'b': fruits}
l = [d1, d2]

for i in l:
    if not d:
        d.update(i)
    else:
        for k in d.keys():
            d[k].extend(i[k])
            

print(f"{d=}")
```

Current output:

```
d={'a': ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo'], 'b': ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo']}
```

Expected output:

```
d={'a': ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo'], 'b': ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry']}
```

Error, I am getting an extra items for `key b`.

What I am missing?

Comment: Would this make sense? `d = {"a" : fruits + cars, "b": cars + fruits}`

Comment: During the second run of your loop `d` isn't empty anymore and so you add the values frome each dictionary again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your problem happens is that the original `fruits` list is modified after the first `for k in d.keys()` iteration in the second `for i in l` iteration. At this point, the original `fruits` contains all the fruits *and* all the cars.

Since you defined both dictionaries to contain the same two lists (instead of creating a copy), the list at `d2['b']` (which *is* `fruits`) now contains all fruits and cars. When you extend `d['b']` (which already contains all cars) with this list, the result is duplicated cars.

As you've correctly identified [in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77309254/843953), one solution is to *add* the two lists instead of `.extend`, which creates a new list containing elements from both lists instead of modifying the original. [Roman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77309165/843953) uses the same idea.

[Matthias's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77309247/843953) works because they used a defaultdict, which creates this new list for you whenever `d[key]` doesn't exist (which is always for the first time that key is encountered), and extends *that* list. The original lists are never modified.

Similarly, another solution would be to *copy* the lists instead of just updating `d` in the `if not d` case (provided, of course, that the potential problem of `d1` and `d2` having different keys is not an issue)

```
for i in l:
    if not d:
        for k in i.keys():
            d[k] = i[k].copy()
    else:
        for k in d.keys():
            d[k].extend(i[k])
```

which also gives the expected solution:

```
{'a': ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo'],
 'b': ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry']}
```

Comment: Hi pho, Thanks for the detailed explanation. I will use this solution. Also, In my answer I modified the changes suggested by @JonSG.

Answer (score 1):

Those `update/extend` are just the unneeded overcomplication in your case. Use simple dict comprehension:

```
d = {k: v + d2[k] for k, v in d1.items()}
print(d)
```

---

```
{'a': ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo'],
 'b': ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry']}
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers do not deal with the case where there are different keys in the dictionary. If such a thing can happen, a solution with a `defaultdict` could be useful.

```
from collections import defaultdict

fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
cars = ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo']

d1 = {'a': fruits, 'b': cars}
d2 = {'a': cars, 'b': fruits, 'c':['A', 'B']}
dictionaries = [d1, d2]

d = defaultdict(list)
for entry in dictionaries:
    for key, values in entry.items():
        d[key].extend(values)

print(f"{d=}")
```

Result

````
d=defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo'], 'b': ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry'], 'c': ['A', 'B']})```
````

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The order is important.As suggested by @JonSG, I replaced `extend` with `+`. It is giving expected output.

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']

cars = ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo']

d = {}
d1 = {'a': fruits, 'b': cars}
d2 = {'a': cars, 'b': fruits}
l = [d1, d2]

for i in l:
    if not d:
        d.update(i)
    else:
        for k in d.keys():
            d[k] = d[k] + i[k]
            

print(f"{d=}")
```

Output:

```
d={'a': ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo'], 'b': ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry']}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the items in the list is not6 important you can use `dict.fromkeys`

```
d = dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b'], [*fruits, *cars])

# {'a': ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo'],
#  'b': ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo']}
```

Comment: `fromkeys` as a side-effect when the default value is a  mutable objects: `d['a'][1] = None` will "update" also the list in `b`

Answer (score 0):

I will go with @JonSG :)

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']

cars = ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo']

d = {"a" : fruits + cars, "b": cars + fruits}

print(d)

# {'a': ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo'], 'b': ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Volvo', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry']}
```

Comment: I second this answer!

Comment: Really? "Hardcode the result you want" isn't a good answer.